# Further Specifying Select -unique in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, select, unique

I'm using PowerShell to reformat a large database.  The raw data consists of device tag names and data points.  The original file repeats the tags for each data point.  Additionally, there are many similar (not identical) tags with identical data points.  Here is a sample of the original:

```
40028 "ALBENI F1" "1 "     0.00   -14.00    12.10
40028 "ALBENI F1" "1 "     2.70   -13.90    11.80
40028 "ALBENI F1" "1 "     4.50   -13.80    11.60
40028 "ALBENI F1" "1 "     7.30   -13.60    11.10
40028 "ALBENI F1" "1 "    10.00   -12.70    10.40
40028 "ALBENI F1" "1 "    12.30   -11.80     9.70
40028 "ALBENI F1" "1 "    12.70   -11.30     9.50
40028 "ALBENI F1" "1 "    14.50    -9.40     8.70
40028 "ALBENI F1" "1 "    16.30    -7.40     7.80
40028 "ALBENI F1" "1 "    16.80    -6.80     6.90
40028 "ALBENI F1" "1 "    17.20    -5.50     5.30
40028 "ALBENI F1" "1 "    17.80    -3.50     3.50
40028 "ALBENI F1" "1 "    18.20     0.00     0.00
40030 "ALBENI F2" "2 "     0.00   -14.00    12.10
```

In Powershell, I've managed to get it looking like so:

```
40028 "ALBENI F1 " "1 " "YES"
 , 0.00, -14.00, 12.10,
 , 2.70, -13.90, 11.80,
 , 4.50, -13.80, 11.60,
 , 7.30, -13.60, 11.10,
 , 10.00, -12.70, 10.40,
 , 12.30, -11.80, 9.70,
 , 12.70, -11.30, 9.50,
 , 14.50, -9.40, 8.70,
 , 16.30, -7.40, 7.80,
 , 16.80, -6.80, 6.90,
 , 17.20, -5.50, 5.30,
 , 17.80, -3.50, 3.50,
 , 18.20, 0.00, 0.00,
  40063 "CGS " "1 " "YES"
 , 0.00, -620.00, 680.00,
```

This is the format I want.  As you can see, I turned all the tags into single headers, and got rid of ALBENI F2, since it is a repeat of F1.  My problem is that to get there, I used `select-object -unique`.  This got rid of all the duplicate headers and repeat data sets, as needed.  However, it also deleted repeat data points on other, completely different tags.  This is unacceptable; so, I need a way to get rid of duplicate tags and data sets, while keeping all data points on unique tags, even if those data points are identical to those from other tags.

If it helps, here is my code:

```
Get-Content (inputfile)|select -skip 2| select-string '}' -NotMatch |
    %{$_ -replace '"\s+(\-?\d+\.\d+)\s+(\-?\d+\.\d+)\s+(\-?\d+\.\d+)','"" ,, $1, $2, $3,'}| 
    %{$_ -split '"\s+,'} |
    select -unique |
    %{$_ -replace '"\s+("\w+")', ' " $1 "YES"'}| 
    %{$_ -replace '"\s+("\w+\s+")', ' " $1 "YES"'} |(outputfile)
```

There's a lot in there, and it all works like it should. I just need another method of sorting out duplicates.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I took a completely different approach;  I first split the file into headers and data.  I then filtered the headers with get-unique, leaving the data alone.  Then I split the data into sets and inserted the appropriate headers in each spot.  This got rid of all the extra headers, and put the whole file into the format I needed.  My entire code is below.

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(mandatory=$true,position=1)]
[string]$InputFilePath,
[Parameter(mandatory=$true,position=2)]
[string]$OutputFilePath
)

Get-Content $InputFilePath |select -skip 2| select-string '}' -NotMatch|%{$_ -replace '"\s+(\-?\d+\.\d+)\s+(\-?\d+\.\d+)\s+(\-?\d+\.\d+)','"" ,, $1, $2, $3,'}| %{$_ -split '"\s+,'} |%{$_ -replace '"\s+("\w+")', ' " $1 "YES"'}| %{$_ -replace '"\s+("\w+\s+")', ' " $1 "YES"'}|out-file $OutputFilePath
$data=Get-Content $OutputFilePath| select-string ',' 
$data=$data|%{$_ -replace '(,\s+0.00,\s+\-?\d+\.\d+\,\s+\d+\.\d+)',':$1'}| %{$_ -split ':'}
$headers=Get-Content $OutputFilePath| select-string '"' | Get-Unique
$counter=0
$data | %{if($_.length -eq 0){$_ -replace '', ($headers|Select-Object -index $counter) ;$counter=$counter+1 }else{$_} }|out-file $OutputFilePath
```

This is my full code, but the important part for this problem is where I start assigning variables.  Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a different approach here, and convert your data into objects which you can then more easily filter on:

```psh
$data = Get-Content $inputfile -Raw # PowerShell 3+
#$data = (Get-Content $inputfile) -join '\n' # Use this with PowerShell 2
$obj = $data -replace ' {2,}', ' ' | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' '
```

Now you have a collection of objects with properties, and you can do filtering however you want, for example:

```psh
$obj | Where-Object { $_.40028 -eq 40028 }
```

For better readability, you might want to pipe to `Format-Table` to see how this is really working.

It's a bit unclear from your question what you're ultimately trying to get out of this, so it's hard to demonstrate more specific queries. It would also help if you had headers for each of the columns as it would result in more meaningful property names.

### Explanation

```psh
$data -replace ' {2,}', ' ' | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimeter ' '
```

This is collapsing all instances of 2 or more spaces down to a single space, which will help with converting to CSV.

We tell `ConvertFrom-Csv` that we're using a single space as a delimeter, and then it work its magic. It understands quoted fields, so this works well here.

If you had headers you could specify them with `-Header` so that the resulting properties have good names.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason the final format is so weird is that this table is just being fed into a FORTRAN script.  The script is already being used, we just got data from an outside source.  I'll try your suggestion tomorrow.

Comment: Unfortunately, this leaves me with the same basic problem.  I'm trying to do conditional filtering.  If I was filtering from properties, your method would be awesome.  However, I'm trying to filter out data sets if they're identical to other data sets, while keeping individual points that may be identical to other points (by chance).  Simultaneously, I want to make it so each of my unique data sets has one header, with no extra labels.  All this has to be in a very specific syntax so it can be fed into a FORTRAN program.  Thanks for the input though, that's a good tool I can use in the future.